# Emscripten C++ 11 Standard Library support

Tags: c++11, emscripten

Does emscripten has full support for C++11 Standard Library?

Specifically - what will happen if I use any of the concurrency related constructs, e.g std::async, std::lock_guard etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Emscripten uses libc++, so it has quite complete STL support, except for things the JS platform can't handle, such as threads. Things like atomics will work (but do nothing special, because no threads exist).